# Finding all quadratic residues $\pmod{n}$ in sublinear time?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, quadratic-residues

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $R_n$ be the set of quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose we are given access to a factorization for $n$ into prime powers $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$. Is there a way to list all elements of $R_n$ in $O(|R_n|)$ time? Clearly one can square all $m$ in $1 \le m \le \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$, but if $|R_n| \ll n$ this can be prohibitive.

If that's too hard, since $|R_n| = \prod_{i=1}^k |R_{p_i^{e_i}}|$, suppose we were given some precomputation time for each $p_i^{e_i} < N$, for some upper bound $N$, where $n < N$, and we had to list $R_n$ for several such $n$ (allowing us to amortize some of the precomputation). Could we then more quickly solve the Chinese Remainder Theorem systems $\{ x \equiv r_i \pmod{p_i^{e_i}}\}$, for each tuple $(r_1, \dots, r_k)$ such that $r_i$ is in $R_{p_i^{e_i}}$, which would yield each $x \in R_n$?

Comment: It's known that $|R_n|>n^{1-\epsilon}$ for large $n$. Thus any speed-up would be negligible. Is it known that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{|R_n|}{n}=0$? If this were not the case, then $n$ and $|R_n|$ would be asymptotically equivalent (with respect to $\Theta(\cdot)$). In any case, I can't really see the motivation for this question.

Comment: The motivation is a recent Project Euler problem, wherein it is useful to compute, and iterate over, $R_n$ for all $n$ between 1 and a certain large number. Since $|R_n|$ can be much smaller than $n/2$, this could in practice speed up a solution.